# EWS API ExchnageWebServices Update() method on Contacts

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Will updating just a few Contact properties like say "JobTitle" for a single Contact object using EWS Managed API will overwrite the whole Contact and just set a JobTitle properti or will it just update that Property and preserve the other values?

I wish the documentation for this API was better.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: include link to the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes are made at the property level in EWS so it will just update the property you change (when you say "other values" what are you expecting to be overwritten?). But the best thing to do is actually write some code and test it yourself as there are some exceptions are DisplayNames etc.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "overwrite" ? if you change a property in a contact, this property will be changed, the LastModifiedTime property and ChangeKey also, maybe other properties may change ( it depends on the property you are changing, if you change the first name, it's normal that the DisplayedName change), but the ID of the contact won't change, so you can consider that the contact is not overwritten.

Comment: Interesting I didn't know about the LastModifiedTime property's existence, I will do more research on that,I appreciate the answer.